# Pass variable like an input id in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Good day. I am still learning Javascript. And I have a function that is called by this button:

```
<input class='inputButton' type='button' onclick="submit_data('EDIT')">
```

The function of submit_data looks like this:

```
function submit_data(mode){
var txtName = $('#txtName').val();
}
```

Where txtName is the id of a textbox. But suppose I have a variable called `$xDate` how do I call it?

```
var xDate =  $('$xDate').val();
```

like this?

This is the whole submit_data:

```
function submit_data(mode){
var txtName = $('#txtName').val();
varUrl = "/includes/action.php";
varData = "MODE=" + mode + "&TXT_NAME=" + txtName;

     $.ajax({
          url: varUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: varData,
          success: function(result) {
              alert(result);
              if(result = 'success'){
                redirect_to_parent();
              } 
              else
              {
              }
          }
     });
}
```

And the action.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once("/includes/functions.php");

$_GETVARS = (($_GET <0) ? $_GET : $_POST);

$mode = $_GETVARS['MODE'];
switch ($mode){    
    case 'EDIT': 
break;

    default:
        print_r($_GETVARS);
        break;
}

?>
```

In short. I need my variable to be accessible in action php. Possibly be included in my $_GETVARS

Sorry for the confusion. $xDate is a variable. I cannot get it from textbox and exist only as a variable.

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`? Please add complete code in question

Comment: `$('#'+$xDate).val();`? Considering `$xDate` contains ID.

Comment: What is `$xDate`? What is stored in it?

Comment: Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: $xDate is just a variable. Because I am passing values from textbox. But $xDate is from a variable and can not be obtain via textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If the element your want to get an element to is linked to an id

```
$('#' + $xDate).val();
```

or, if it's a class

```
$('.' + $xDate).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
<input class='inputtext' type='text'id="$xDate"/>

<input class='inputButton' type='button' onclick="submit_data('$xDate')"/>

function submit_data(mode){
    var txtName = $('#'+mode).val();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your supposed to pass javascript variable to jquery as

```
 $('#' + $xDate).val();
```